# Aliasing functions and definitions in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a set of **C** API functions/definitions prefixed: Abc_* and ABC_*

```
Abc_Function1(int a);
#define ABC_TEST 1
```

In the next version of the API, I need to rename all of these to: `Xyz_*` and `XYZ_*`

To avoid breaking the flow for people using the previous version of the API, I want to making some compatibility definitions such that the user may invoke the same function using `Abc_Function1()` or `Xyz_Function1()`.

I've tried the following:

```
Xyz_Function1(int a);
#define XYZ_TEST 1

#define Abc_ Xyz_
#define ABC_ XYZ_
...
Xyz_Function1(ABC_TEST); // Returns an error (ABC_TEST not defined)
Abc_Function1(XYZ_TEST); // Returns an error (implicit Abc_Function1)
```

When I try to use `XYZ_TEST` or `Xyz_Function1()` by using the, I would have expected that the preprocessor renames the user's usage of `Abc_*` and `ABC_*` to `Xyz_*` and`XYZ_*` but it doesn't work.

Is there anything I'm missing or is there another way to do this?

Comment: If it is not prohibitive, support both versions for  a while to allow your users migrate to the new naming convention. Or provide a script that the users can run in their code base to make all the necessary changes.

Comment: AFAIK, the preprocessor can replace *complete* names only! What you are trying to do is to replace part of variable/function names!

Comment: Q: Why do you need to change the names completely?  It is something to do in extremis — certainly not an exercise to indulge in lightly.  Observations: I don't think there's a good way to do it other than `#define ABC_TEST XYZ_TEST` to map old macros to new names, and `#define Abc_Function1(a) Xyz_Function1(a)` — rinse and repeat. Or, for the functions, you can have `static inline int Abc_Function1(int a) { return Xyz_Function1(a); }` in the header instead of a macro. You could also provide a (Perl?) script to edit the names from the old to the new form, so it is easier for people to migrate.

Comment: "To avoid breaking the flow for people using the previous version of the API..." - surely if you're changing an API, a hard, clean break is *exactly* what you want? The best reason for the old names to stay in your library at all is so they can cause an error if the user is still using them and make them update their code. Accommodating the use of deprecated features leads to headache later on.